# How successful could rapidly spreading new predator be in world with today's type of development

Tags: military-defense, creature-design

I was rewatching Secret war from Love, Death & Robots and started wondering, would the monsters from that episode pose any actual threat in today's world?
Let's assume the monsters have similar characteristic as the ones in LDR.

- No special magical abilities
- Faster and stronger than humans
- Live and breed underground, but hunt on the surface
- Live in hive like structures. When a hive reaches a certain size it sends out colonizing workers which try to establish a new hive 10 to 100 km away from its original location. The new hive operates as individual entity independent from original hive.
- Mostly nocturnal, but can operate in daylight if forced
- There are several variants of the monsters, where smaller ones develop and mature faster than bigger ones.
- Hunt and kill any animal including humans that comes their way
- Posses enough intelligence to successfully hunt in packs.

For this scenario it is irrelevant if monsters came to Earth through a failed magical ritual or are part of a failed cloning experiment. They exist and until they reach high numbers almost nobody is aware they exist. People become aware of the monsters when they start appearing and hunting in big cities.
Lets put first big hives in the Amazon rainforest in Brasil. First sightings and mass killings happen in Brasils state Para and Mato grosso. How would government and military react to this threat. How fast should monster be able to multiply and expand in order to avoid extermination.

Edit: Added some more specific information.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please read through our [help] to understand what questions we answer. At the moment you are asking 4 questions, which make your post eligible for closure.

Comment: I'm slightly sad this question will probably be closed, because I enjoyed writing my answer about how much of an absolute bastard humans are to fight.

Comment: How can I update question further in order to prevent its being closed.

Comment: "*until they reach high numbers almost nobody is aware they exist*" classic monster-movie trope, utterly unrealistic. Many locals will become aware of  missing livestock, pets, and friends quite rapidly. They might be "*faster and stronger than humans*" (another trope), but they're not faster and stronger than human tools like ordinary firearms. And humans know how to hunt in packs, too. Ask any Mammoth.

Comment: I agree. Initial question originated form Love death and robots episode and I was curious how and if that kind of threat would that monsters pose.

Comment: @user2511383 I'd edit for clarity first, so strip out irrelevant information, then ask one question. Currently you ask two, "How would the government and military react to this threat?" and "How fast would the monsters need to expand to avoid extermination?"

I'd argue we probably can't answer the second one, as it'll depend on a lot of factors, some of them luck and the competence of the military response, what resources are poured into hunting them down, etc

Comment: the other question you could ask is "what would the smallest change be to make these monsters pose a threat to humanity?"

Comment: We have several invaders who match _some_ of these characteristics, ants and feral hogs. (Check out fire ants and crazy ants.) In these cases, people didn't realize the threat until the invaders had become established.

Comment: Have you *met* us?  We're human beings and we're really, *really*, *REALLY* good at killing things.  So good that we're in the middle of our very own extinction event.

Comment: @DavidR also, rabbits in Australia, and rats wherever we go. Maybe the key to surviving humans is to reproduce really quickly and not be all that exciting to hunt. The hogs are the best example, though, because a hogs are at least somewhat dangerous to people.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

## We're humans. We're a walking, talking, ecological disaster

The equivalent of the dinosaur killer comet on legs. Responsible for the death of 70% of land mammals in the last 50 years. We used to hunt the closest thing we have to a multi tonne, ship crushing, kracken eating sea monster for its oil, which burned nicely, and we only stopped *because there were virtually none left*.

The point I'm trying to make is, that if there's one thing our civilization has figured out, it's how to wipe out a species.

First up, I'd argue these won't go unnoticed until they get to cities. Even if they only hunt sheep and not humans, we have this nasty habit of carrying cameras everywhere, and farmers tend to notice sheep vanishing. We're talking 1000 of these things, tops, before someone spots one and starts to take notice.

If they hunt everything, we'd set up decoys, or poisoned or booby trapped baits. Animal traps. A few sheep in a field, and a bunch of hunters.

If they sleep underground, we'd fill their lair with gas. Do they need to breathe? If not, that's fine. We've got nerve gases that are absorbed on skin contact.

A major surge in these would result in a local city lockdown. Snipers would be deployed, we could track the creatures with thermal cameras on helicopters or drones, meaning very little chance of them ambushing us. When they retreat, because pack animals are smart enough to do so, we'd trace them back to their lair, and set it on fire. Or, y'know, gas again, because we're in a city and want to skip out on property damage.

If it turns out they breed too fast, we'll switch to biological warfare - a non earth creature is likely to be pretty safe to target with some home brewed viruses - the odds of us infecting our own population would be small. In the meantime, we'd keep their numbers down by poisoning, trapping, and shooting them.

I predict we'd be absolutely fine. Unless they're an [emu](http://veritablehokum.com/comic/the-emu-war/)

Comment: We don't joke about Emus... *you weren't there mate...*

Comment: I did not think about crossbreading them with emus. That could lead to interesting results ...
Anyway I was worried this would be an answer. Do you think there would be realistic solution/feature this kind of monsters would need to have in order to prove real threat to humanity?

Comment: @user2511383 possibly pointers from the classic sci Fi "Day of the Triffids" - you need an event that damages humanity enough that they can't fight back as easily, I think. Just upping the strength of creatures gets unrealistic fast - a completely bulletproof creature, for example, is unlikely. Most things need intact organs to survive, and to keep whatever means they have of circulating oxygen and nutrients in it's container. Most things will also, to achieve a decent metabolism, have to have high pressure bits, making bullets particularly dangerous.

Comment: If they were behaviorally predisposed (somehow) towards targeting rural areas, then this could go on for far longer before it was taken seriously. Some jackass with pictures of chupacabra isn't going to get serious attention. Smaller hives in rural areas. Hunting people in ways that, at least at first, could be mistaken for (human-on-human) murder. Instinctively avoiding cities until their numbers could make it much more difficult to deal with them. Then you wake up one morning and the population of Montana's just "gone". Even as the army mobilized to go there, it starts happening elsewhere...

Comment: @JohnO I was interested in something a bit like cicadias, as I thought they might be a tough thing to track down. Some creatures prey on a bunch of cows on an isolated farm, eat them, and then either lay and bury eggs that remain dormant for several years, or go dormant themselves. The speed of emergence and short lead time might make it hard to prepare.

Comment: Societies are also really good about reducing problems to not-quite-resolved but tolerable low-intensity issues, like cliffside collapses, beach erosion, and drug smuggling.

Comment: BOnus points for the HFY. Reminds me of a novel where aliens are scared shitless of humans because we are monsters in their eyes.

Comment: Nice answer and I agree with all points. But if these predators have as much intelligence as canids (dogs, foxes, wolves, jackals, coyotes), it might be a different story. Humans have been pretty effective at eliminating wolves, but coyotes are doing well in North America and spreading to fill ecological niches that wolves once did.

Comment: Upvote for setting multi tonne, ship crushing, kracken eating emus on fire.

Comment: @bfris -- we more or less co-oped wolves on a species-to-species basis anyway

Comment: 1000 seems like a vast overestimate before they make world news.  Heck, even yetis have been seen, photographed and put all over the "news", and there isn't even 1 of those.

Comment: @Him I'd probably agree - I think I'd argue that a) there is no way we get above 1000 of these before someone notices, and b) there is no way 1000 of these are a danger to humanity

Comment: @bfis I'd argue that it's because we're not actively trying to wipe them out. If you look at some of the efforts to wipe out wolves in the USA - a sort of policy of elimination at all costs, and so people poisoned and trapped them to close to extinction.  If we did the same with coyotes, I'm sure numbers would plummet.

Comment: they are just too big, too obvious, and hives make them too easy to kill, they would not stand a chance. They just can't hide, notice all the examples of problems we have not solved either involves humans or animals easily mistaken for and who interbreed with dogs, things we are not willing to eradicate on sight.

Comment: I would point out that there are plenty of things that humanity sticks its head in the sand about. By the time these things are confirmed as something other than Weekly World News headlines, it won't be us having wiped them out, but them being a problem that isn't easily managed at all, quite possibly even the existential thread OP is hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

If these monsters were to exist in the real world, the government and military would likely take a multi-faceted approach to dealing with the threat. Initially, they would probably focus on containment, setting up quarantine zones and using military forces to secure the perimeter and prevent the monsters from spreading to other areas. They may also use air and ground forces to try and locate and destroy the hives.

As the situation evolves and more is learned about the monsters, the government may decide to launch a full-scale military operation to eradicate the threat. This would likely involve the use of heavy weapons, such as bombs and missiles, to destroy the hives and kill the monsters.

The speed at which the monsters can multiply and expand would be a critical factor in determining the success of the government's response. If they are able to reproduce and spread quickly, it may become very difficult to eradicate them, and they could pose a significant threat to the population. On the other hand, if the monsters are slow to reproduce and spread, the government may be able to contain and eradicate the threat before it becomes a major problem.

I think that the only way for them to survive is to reproduce so quickly that it would look like mitosis, where 1 becomes 2 and 2 becomes 4 and so on ... we would reach massive numbers in months and wouldn't be able to contain them...

But if the reproduction rate is like us (humans), then they wouldn't be able to reproduce quickly enough to not be noticed, since humans may have only 1 child per year ( or in twin cases a little bit more ).